# How to make a form send email & post form fields to an external URL

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, salesforce

I am using a salesforce web-to-lead form on my website. When i submit the form it redirects to Salesforce link and creates a new lead.

I want the form to **first send me an email notification** of form details and then open the salesforce to add lead.

How can i make the form do this?

```
<form action="https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToCase?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">
<input  type=hidden name="orgid" value="00D5g000000IUJD">
<input type=hidden name="retURL" value="https://mytimios.com/thank-you">
<input class="formelem" style="width:100%;" id="name" maxlength="80" name="name" size="30"  type="text" placeholder="Name" required="true" /><br>
<input class="formelem" style="width:100%;" id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="text" placeholder="Email" required="true" /><br>
<input class="formelem" style="width:100%;"  id="phone" maxlength="40" name="phone" size="20" type="text" placeholder="Phone Number" required="true" /><br>
<select style="width:100%;" id="00N5g000003uiad" name="00N5g000003uiad" title="Category" required="true"><option value="">--Select Issue Type--</option><option value="Tracking Order">Tracking Order</option>
<option value="Delivery Issue">Delivery Issue</option>
<option value="Quality Issue">Quality Issue</option>
</select><br>
<input class="formelem" style="width:100%;" id="subject" maxlength="80" name="subject" size="20" type="text" placeholder="Subject" required="true" /><br>
<textarea name="description" placeholder="Description" ></textarea><br>
<input class="formelem" style="width:100%;" id="00N5g000003uiae" maxlength="20" name="00N5g000003uiae" size="20" type="text" placeholder="Order Reference Number" required="true" /><br>
<select style="width:100%;" id="00N5g000003uiaf" name="00N5g000003uiaf" title="Sub Category" required="true"><option value="">--Select Issue Sub Type--</option><option value="Delay in the Delivery">Delay in the Delivery</option>
<option value="Damage Product">Damage Product</option>
<option value="Incomplete Delivery">Incomplete Delivery</option>
<option value="Misplaced  package">Misplaced  package</option>
</select><br>
<input id="subbtn" type="submit" name="submit" >
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to have to either:

a)  break the submit process into 2 ajax requests (the first to your own back-end or an email service) and the second to salesforce.

or b) send the form data to your own back end, where you'll process and send yourself an email, then send salesforce the new lead via their api.